# call function in context of buffer

Tags: vimscript, buffers

How can I call a function in vimscript in the context of a specified buffer?

For instance, `line2byte` works for the current buffer. I am implementing a callback, where I receive a buffer number as an argument and I need to call `line2byte` for the specified buffer, which might not be the one currently focused by the user.

Answer (score 6):

You can temporarily change the buffer before calling `line2byte`. However, you need to be careful. In particular, you should avoid changing the alternate file and prevent autocommands from firing. For this, you need `keepalt` and `noautocmd`, respectively.

Something like this should work, where I assume the `lnum` is supplied as an argument as well (untested):

```
function! Line2ByteBuf(bufnr, lnum) abort
  let l:bufnr = bufnr('')

  execute 'noautocmd keepalt buffer' a:bufnr
  let l:bytes = line2byte(a:lnum)
  execute 'noautocmd keepalt buffer' l:bufnr

  return l:bytes
endfunction
```

Note that you should probably also add a check if the supplied buffer `bufnr` exists and similar. I left that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `noautocmd`.

Comment: BTW, IIRC, it should be `bufnr('%')`.

Comment: Thanks, Luc! I've fixed the `bufnr` error. Note, `bufnr('')` and `bufnr('%')` is equivalent, so I chose the shortest form.

Comment: I didn't know about `bufnr('')` either. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If your function does not take a *bufnr* as parameter and if there is no alternative function that does, you'll need to jump to that particular buffer and call your function.

<del>The caveat? It'll trigger autocommands, which means stuff you may not desire is likely to happen.</del> EDIT: I didn't know about `noautocmd` which prevents autocommands from being triggered when loading other buffers momentarily. See @Karl Yngve Lervåg's answer.

In your particular case though, it seems that `line2byte(lnum+1)` is almost identical to `eval(join(map(getbufline(bufnr, 1, lnum), 'strlen(v:val)'), '+'))+lnum+1`.

If the line ending is not unix, the offset may be `&ff =='unix' ? lnum+1 : 2*lnum+2` -- I haven't checked dos case, nor mixed line endings.

Regarding the second question: "how to emulate `byte2line()`?", it can be done this way:

```
function! bufbyte2line(bufid, byteidx) abort
    let lines = map(getbufline(a:bufid, 1, '$'), 'v:val."\n"')
    let line_lengths = map(lines, 'len(v:val)')
    let acc = [0]
    call map(line_lengths, 'add(acc, acc[-1]+v:val)')
    return len(filter(acc, 'v:val <= a:byteidx'))
endfunction
```

Comment: Do you also have such a version for the opposite function: `byte2line`?

Comment: I guess we should be able to play with `map()` + maybe `add()` to accumulate bytes and `filter()` with a threshold to keep the right number of lines which (this number) should be your result. I'll see what I can do for the sake of the exercise. But honestly, I didn't know about `noautocmd`, you'd better go along with @Karl's solution.